# Android remove navigation bar divider

Tags: android

Is it possible to remove navigation bar divider?
On android emulator there is no this divider, on xiaomi divices it appears. Using `window.setNavigationBarDividerColor(getColor(R.color.white))` does not solves problem.

[image: divider]

Comment: Make your screen fully and use light navigation bar with transparent color.